# Python3 array of string serialization to JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

**Environment:**  Python3.6

**Problem:**
I have a result set from database as below:

```
Row1 a, b, c, d, e . 
Row2 a, b, c, d, f . 
Row3 a, b, l, m, o . 
Row4 a, b, l, m, p
```

**Expected Result:**
The JSON object should be as follows:

```
{
    a, b,  
    {[c, d,  
        [{e, 
          f}]],  
    {l, m,  
        [{o, 
          p}]]
}
```

**Question:**
What is the best way to accomplish if the volume is < 1000 rows?

Comment: What format is your result set in? Is this a list of iterables?

Comment: The JSON object format doesn't look correct - is the top level data structure an array of items?

Comment: @MaximKukhtenkov This is the format. I am sorry about the confusion in original post
{
 a,
 b,
 [c, d, [{
  e,
  f
 }]],
 [l, m, [{
  o,
  p
 }]]
}

Comment: @ggorlen: It is a JSON object and yes iterables.

Comment: I think I understand - the way you alternate braces for readability is misleading since in JSON notation curly braces indicate key-value combinations while square ones indicate a list of items. I assume you expect the following output `["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e", "f"]], ["l", "m", ["o", "p"]]]` ?  It looks like a coding problem/exercise - did you try to do it first? What issue or error did you face with your implementation?

Comment: I'm confused about the result format. Anything inside of `{}` needs to have key-value pairs separated by `:`, so Maxim's above suggestion of nested arrays is the only valid proposal so far as I can see. For the input data, is the period `.` part of the data? The question needs clarification.